# jquery add class onclick include div

Tags: jquery, onclick

please how do I create?
click include div GRAY change background prev div red only click box, other boy white

```js
$('.box .center').click(function() {
   $('.box').removeClass('red');
   $('.box').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
.center {margin: 40px 100px; width: 50px; height: 25px; background: gray;  display: block; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/

Comment: This is confusing `click include div GRAY change background prev div red only click box, other boy white`.

Comment: Dear user2851761, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is hard to understand language-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```js
$('.box .center').click(function() {
   $('.box').removeClass('red');
   $(this).parent('.box').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}
.center {margin: 40px 100px; width: 50px; height: 25px; background: gray;  display: block; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```